# Setting attribute of htmlElement doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, setattribute

I have encounter a strange problem. I am trying to login a website using a **webbrowser** by setting the value attributes of two inputs and invoking a click on a submit input, one input is for a username and the other for the password.

```cs
        HtmlElement tempElement;

         // typing email of the user to the email textbox.
        tempElement = browser.Document.GetElementById("txtUserName");
        tempElement.SetAttribute("value", userName);

        // typing password of the user to the password textbox.
        tempElement = browser.Document.GetElementById("txtPassoword");
        tempElement.SetAttribute("value", "123456");
```

Now setting the value of the username input worked as needed but setting the value of the password input didn't work.
I tried to change only the **OuterHtml** of the password input but it still not changing, it seems that every thing a try to change on the password input isn't working.

Does someone know why setting the value attribute of the password input doesn't work?

Comment: is this a direct copy/paste from your code? If it is, correct "txtPassowrd" to "txtPassword", or whatever the backing field's id is.

Comment: Its ok, I am copying the id straight from the source code of the site.